# Cloth inflation error

Tags: modeling, physics, cloth-simulation

I am trying to model a coffee pouch and below is a picture.

[image]

Below is a mesh of what ive modelled so far,
and the highlighted vertices are where pressure physics are applied to.
(excluded vertices are all pin group)

[image]

Below is what I got as a result :

[image]

as you can see the top and bottom parts of the inflated area are sort of blurred
and I cant figure out why this is happening.
I was trying to get the clean distinction line between the pin group and the inflated area.

Below is my phsyics tab

[image]

How can I get rid of the blurs?

Let me know if I need to provide any other details

Thank you all as always! :)

Comment: +  "shade smooth" + auto smooth 30* normals is already applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want harder edges, just insert some more loopcuts to your vertex group, which are pinned like this:

[image]

then you get:

[image]

same you could do on the long edges...if you like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way I found is changing the auto smooth degree.

[image]